# FFMPEG delay creating segments

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I was trying to do HLS streaming. The file segments were created using FFMPEG. While creating segments FFMPEG buffers some amount of data say about 5-10 seconds so that the generated segments are delayed by about 5-10 seconds. Is there some way so that i can overcome this delay?

Comment: Minimum delay is equal to the media segment duration. ffmpeg decoding/encoding speedup strongly depends on the incoming stream codec. There will be no general answer to such question.

Comment: sorry for not including the number of segments and segment duration. I used 3 segments each of 1 second duration. so the duration of the buffered data will be around 3 seconds but FFMPEG is buffering about 10 seconds of data.